# Sempre redirecionar para HTTPS com Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, https

Tenho uma aplicação com CodeIgniter e preciso forçar sempre a conexão redirecionar sempre para `https`.

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

1. Alterei dentro de `config\config.php` a linha
   `$config['enable_hooks']` para `TRUE`.
2. Dentro de `config\hooks.php`
   adicionei as linhas.

   ```
   $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
       'function' => 'redirect_ssl', 
       'filename' => 'ssl.php', 
       'filepath' => 'hooks'
   );
   ```
3. Na pasta `hooks` criei o arquivo `ssl.php` com a seguinte função:

   ```
   function redirect_ssl() {
       $CI =& get_instance();
       $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
       $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
       if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
           // redirecting to ssl.
           $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
           if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
       } else {
           // redirecting with no ssl.
           $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
           if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
       }
   }
   ```

Após efetuar o teste a pagina ate e redirecionada para `https://` mais vem o erro no Chrome:

> Esta página não está funcionando
>   Redirecionamento em excesso por meusite.com
>   Tente limpar os cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: Esse tipo de redirecionamento pode ser feito direto pelo servidor de dns ao invés de pelo código, no cloudflare em crypto > Always use HTTPS  você pode configurar para fazer esse redirecionamento automático, eu sei que não resolve o seu problema, mais serve como uma possível opção.

Comment: Eu estou com o cloudflare. E ele não está fazendo automatico.

Comment: por padrão ele não redireciona, tem que alterar as configurações na aba Crypto

Comment: Não acredito. Deu certo. kkkk Não conhecia essa função. Em `base_url` agora so preciso forçar a troca de `http` para `https`.

Answer (score 1):

Opa. 
É mais seguro você fazer o redirecionamento no .htaccess e também no CodeIgniter. 
Htaccess
01 - Crie um arquivo com o nome ".htaccess"
02 - E coloque entro dele
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nomedosite.com.br/$1 [R,L]

Mas é interessante fazer também no codeigniter
seguindo as instruções nesse link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503663/force-https-www-for-codeigniter-in-htaccess-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: Vou testar pelo arquivo então. A que ponto de vista seria mais seguro?

Comment: Vou melhorar o texto.